Lock out a user using ASP.NET Core Identity
Has anyone figured out a way to lock out users using ASP.NET Core Identity?
I've found you can set LockoutEnd to a datetime in the future and that user will not be able to log in. However, users don't need to log in every time they go to the site. The site remembers their login for something like 30 days. So they would be able to continue using the site for up to 30 days!
Is there any way to lock them out immediately?

"users don't need to log in every time they go to the site" - that depends on your cookie/session policy

@Dai: By default, users do not need to log in every time. And more importantly, that's how it's configured on my site. We could talk about that some more, but not having to log in every time they navigate to my site is an important feature, and not something I'd want to change. That's why being able to lock them out immediately is a critical part of my question.

BTW, the term Lockout in ASP.NET Core Identity refers to the rules that prevent further login-attempts from people trying to guess passwords (e.g. by running a dictionary-attack to the login <form>) but it sounds like you're looking for Access Revocation - not automatic-lockout, right?#

@Dai: I want to prevent them from accessing the site. I understand lockout generally refers to being disabled from too many log in attempts. But locked out is what I'd call preventing them from using the site as well. But honestly, it doesn't matter what you'd like to call it.

@Dai: Thanks, but Edge is reporting that site as a phishing site. I will try Googling ISecurityStampValidator.

Oh wow, what the heck - you're right. That website is proxying MS's own API docs - I wasn't paying attention to the URI, one moment. I've deleted the bad link now.

Here's the real link (phew!): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#isecuritystampvalidator-and-signout-everywhere

@Dai: Cool, thanks! I'll check it out.

Considered using policies with authorization?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Policies can't trigger a reissuing or revocation of the cookies or Ticket object from CookiesAuthentication

@JonathanWood Define "immediately". A literal immediate effect would require checking some criteria/flag for every request made. This followed by storage access to check flag state + cache that would be reset after access revoking action. All this sounds like custom logic that you should implement on your own. Implementation details of such mechanism will differ depending on cookie/session policy, as Dai mentioned.
